# Using Textbox ReportItems! value in a calculated field

Tags: reporting-services

How do I create a calculated field in dataset#2 using a field in dataset#1 that I have put into a textbox? I have 2 datasets - DS1 and DS2.  DS1 has a field called 'Country' where the value can be either 'Argentina', 'Chile', etc.  DS2 has a field called 'Revenue'. I need to format the Revenue field in DS2 based on the country field in DS1.  Since calculated fields cannot use Lookup nor any aggregate function, I put the country field in a textbox on the report. I then tried to define a calculated field in DS2 referencing the value in the textbox using ReportItems! function - **IIF(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value="Argentina", Fields!Revenue.Value*100,Fields!Revenue.Value)** but get error saying 'Unknown Expression Type: FieldValue denying ReportItems"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only ever have a single value in `ds1` then you can do something like

```
=IIF(
     FIRST(Fields!Country.Value, "ds1") = "Argentina",
     Fields!Revenue.Value * 100,
     Fields!Revenue.Value
    )
```

If you have more than a single entry in `ds1` then this won't work and you will need to provide more info, sample data and expected results based on the sample data.

Comment: Fields can't be defined with functions like First, Max, Min, Lookup.  So I thought i would test out by adding a textbox and adding the field in there and in my calculated field I would reference the textbox using ReportItems!Textbox1.Value, but get the aforementioned error msg.  Corp security prevents me from uploading images, files, etc.

Comment: You can't do that, dataset can only 'see' what's in the dataset already. I think you are trying to solve a problem the wrong way but unless you share more, nobody will be able to help without a lot of luck guess what you are trying to do. I can't believe you can't upload a picture of a mockup that has no sensitive information in it? If that is the case then you'll struggle to get help.